# Can my spouse attend university in Cyprus on dependent visa?

Tags: dependent-visa, students

I am a non-EU citizen with a working visa in Cyprus (am employed as software engineer). My spouse is on dependent visa with me in Cyprus. Can my spouse attend university in Cyprus on dependent visa?

Thanks,

Comment: This asks what the law permits. It does not ask for specific legal advice as this site defiens that. It should not be closed on that basis.